# Show Markup column only in selected pages

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, comments, markup

I have a .doc document which has comments and the markup column (call it A), and I want to insert it in a bigger document (B), which is the plain format master document. When I insert A to B, B takes the format of A and the markup column is being inserted in the whole B. How can I change that?

I tried working in different sections, via the break, and insert text via 'Insert object', but B keeps obtaining the markup column. Google did not help.

Is there any way that I can disassociate completely different pages in one word document, and therefore only selected pages in the whole document have the markup collumn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mark up column isn't a document feature that is copied from one document to another, instead it's a feature of the Word editor itself which appears over the whole document when there is markup such as comments or revisions to be viewed and can be [turned on and off from the ribbon.](http://ooiks.com/blog/uncategorized/microsoft-word-2013-remove-markup-area)

I hope this explains why it appears and why there won't be any way for it to appear on a certain subset of pages only. In order to localize markup to one page you may want to think of using textboxs and shapes instead of comments.